# Request to get all possible API endponts of API

Tags: curl

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to creating requests to API's. I have pretty much only performed GET or POST requests, but I was wondering if there is any request that one could make to an API that would return all of the possible endpoints you can request to?
Something like:

```
curl -getOptions http://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

I general, no, there is not. You will have to refer to whatever documentation the site might have.

However, some sites might offer an endpoint for downloading an API specification. Particularly, if they are using OpenAPI or Swagger. Even in that case, you would likely find the information in human readable documentation somewhere.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense. In the case they are using OpenAPI or Swagger, would there be a general endpoint for downloading the API specification or would that differ from vendor to vendor?